# WP functions.php in Child Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, parent-child, child-process

I have added footer content and header menu to the parent theme.

Trying to enqueue styles in the child theme's `functions.php` but it is not working.

I have done the tweaking on the parent theme.

How do I add this function to child theme, how do i start writing my plugin??

```
function wptuts_styles_with_a_lot(){

    wp_register_style()
    wp_enqueue_style()

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'wptuts_styles_with_a_lot' );
```

Comment: Is there actually a space in that function name? between `wptuts_styles_with_a` and `lot()`

Comment: ' wp_register_style' google this - like all php functions it has ()  after its name to identify it as calling a function and it takes variables. In terms of using a child theme, google this as well, it tells you how to set it up so theres a functions.php and style.css. You can place your hook in the functions.php file and it will load.

Comment: Thanks David, the 'hook' is not written here completely thats why I am missing () names. when i google child theme set up, it shows no 'functions.php' files are overwritten... there must be a line of code that does this for Child theme. at the moment I have placed it in the Parent theme in functions.php and it works fine. But will it still be there after updates?

Answer (score 0):

Child theme worked when i added the hook bellow, with < ? php (no space) to start with in functions.php
What was making a bug was a header.php file with whole html design merged with Parent code, drop down menu is changing postion in overriden file. but it works fine in parent theme...